# Ratio estimators in sampling

Tags: self-study, estimation, sampling, bias, ratio

> It is intended to estimate the number of dead trees of certain species
>   a forest reserve. The reserve is divided into 200 areas of 1.5
>   hectares. O number of dead trees is measured using aerial photography
>   (X) in 200 areas having a total count of approximately 15,600 dead
>   trees species. In 10 of the 200 areas, the number of dead trees beyond
>   the assessment by aerial photography is also evaluated by land count
>   (Y). the Results are shown in the table below.
>
> $$\begin{bmatrix}Area:1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10\\X_i:12&39&24&24&18&30&12&6&36&42\\Y_i:18&42&24&36&24&36&14&10&48&54\end{bmatrix}$$
>
> a)Find using simple random sampling with replacement an estimate for
>   the number of dead trees and also an estimate of their variance.
>
> b) Find the bias for the mean number of dead trees
>
> c) Recalculate estimates without using the auxiliary variable X and
>   compare Results achieved.
>
> d) Recalculate the previous items now considering simple random sampling without replacement

What I did

a)Let $\hat{\tau_y}$ an estimative for total $Y$ and $r=\frac{\overline{y}}{\overline{x}}$ then
$$\hat{\tau_y}=r\tau_x=\frac{\overline{y}}{\overline{x}}\tau_x=\frac{30.6}{23.4}15600=20400$$

$$s^2_R=\frac{1}{n-1}\sum (Y_i-rX_i)^2=12.076$$

$$\hat{Var(\tau_y)}=\tau_x^2*\frac{s_R^2}{n\mu_x^2}=15600^2*\frac{12.076}{10*23.4^2}=536711$$

b)Let $B$ the bias
$$B=\frac{1}{\mu_x^2}(R\sigma_x^2-p(X,Y)\sigma_x\sigma_y)$$
where $R=\frac{\tau_y}{\tau_x}$ the true ratio and $p(X,Y)$ is the correlation coefficient.Here I am confused if I should just use the sample values $s^2$ and $\overline{x}$ or not

c)$$\hat{\tau_y}=N\overline{y}=200*30.6=6120$$

d)How can I derive the formulas for the case without replacement?

Comment: What's the reference for what you've done so far?

Comment: @SteveSamuels I'm using this book [Book](http://www.amazon.com/Elementos-Amostragem-Em-Portuguese-Brasil/dp/8521203675/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1446898970&sr=8-2&keywords=bolfarine&pebp=1446898978975&perid=1RGQ34TBQNFJGG2TPTHK)